# What size in pixels are GNOME Terminal's column height and row width?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I wish to have an image in my terminal background but I am unsure how big the image needs to be. The terminal is sized at 80x24 which means 80 columns wide and 24 rows high, but I am unable to find anywhere documenting how wide a column itself is. Does anyone happen to know the pixel width of a column/row in Gnome Terminal?

Comment: Don't you want to resize your terminal? I guess the column/row size depends on the fonts you are using.

Comment: No I am happy with my 80x24 size, but those numbers on their own are a useless metric for determining the physical size of the terminal. Without knowing the pixel width of a column it is impossible to know the true width of the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

It's 80x24 characters, so the size depends on the font, e.g. with the 11pt Monospace font it's 722x434 → one character is 9x18px with 1px border around the terminal.

I suggest you make a screenshot of your terminal and determine the size by using the selection tool of GIMP (or go with the easier solution suggested by [AlexTheBird](https://askubuntu.com/users/17079/alexthebird) - just thought if you want to make a background image, you already have GIMP locked and loaded :-)).

Comment: And in gimp you can zoom the image which makes the selection much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You could start the gnome screenshot tool. You can find it in  **Applications menu > Accessories > Take Screenshot**.

1. Select **Select area to grab** hit the <kbd>Take Screenshot</kbd> button and save the image file.
2. Right mouse click on the image file you saved and go to tab *image* and voila... your image size.

Comment: You mean "Grab the current window" and set *Effects* to not include the window border, right? ;-) Also, you would need to disable the menubar to get the right size.

Comment: No, I mean "Select area to grab". Because then you can ... select the area to grab. The area would be the 80x24 Peter mentioned.

Comment: You can select an area of eg. 722x434 pixel-precise? Not bad!

Comment: ok ok, maybe it is a little bit hard to select it pixel-precise. :-)